# Captuar class actual en una variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando capturar el valor de una etiqueta `class` en una variable para después poder usarla en un js, el problema es que el estado de esta clase esta cambiando, y necesito capturar el valor que tenga en el momento

Estoy intentando usar `var x = document.getElementsByClassName()`, pero aun no logro capturar la clase actual en una variable.

Comment: deberias poner mas codigo, y asi poder indentificar el problema, saludos Bro

Answer (score 0):

Usando Jquery puedes usar

```
 var x = $(elem).attr("class");
```

Eso te devuelve el nombre de la clase.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que ingresaste lo que hace es buscar los elementos que tengan ese nombre de clase.

```
   var lsMetal = document.getElementsByClassName("classMetal");
```

Lo que te devolvería una lista de elementos, los cuales podrías manipular de la siguiente forma

```
 var primerMetal = lsMetal[0];
```

Por otra parte lo que estas buscando no viene por este camino, como mencionaron anteriormente si lo que buscas es el nombre de la clase de un elemento, con simple javascript.

```
var myclass = document.getElementById("myDIV").className
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

Lo que hace el método que estas usando es obtener todos los elementos que tengan el valor que le entregas como parámetro.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div id="test" class="xclass">88</div>

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("xclass");
```

Con eso obtendrías el div que tiene la clase que tiene el valor que le das.

En la pregunta no se entiende bien lo que estas buscando.

Si lo que necesitas es obtener el valor del atributo class de un determinado elemento, primero debes determinar como encontrar el elemento en el DOM, por ejemplo si este tiene un id se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("class")
```

te entregara valores similares a los siguientes:

xclass

Si lo que necesitas es el valor de un tag según el nombre de la clase para el mismo caso seria de la siguiente forma.

document.getElementsByClassName("xclass").innerHTML

Esto te entregara: 88

Saludos!